# Unit Testing using Jax RS and pathParam

Tags: java, testing, path, jax-rs, quarkus

I am currently coding a function that would allow a user to start a game from a lobby (a bit like the game among us : the owner click start the game and the game starts.)

To do so, i first get my lobby id (=token) with the path and then check if this lobby exists and if everyone in the lobby is ready.
If this two conditions are validate, I return just a ok code (200).

If i try my request with insomnia request it work well. The issue i have is that i wuld like to create the Unit test function that test this function startGame.

This is my function code :

```
@GET
    @Path("/{token}/start")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response startGame(@PathParam("token") String token) {
        
        if (!sessionsDB.sessionExist(token)){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        if(!userLobbyDB.isEveryoneReady(token)) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).build();
        }   
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

and there is my testing function :

```
@Test
    public void startGame_Test() {
        // ----------- Init des DB ----------- // 
        
        SessionsDB sessionsDB = SessionsDB.getInstance();
        UserDB userDB = UserDB.getInstance();
        UserInLobbyDB userLobbyDB = UserInLobbyDB.getInstance();
        
        
        // ----------- Création d'une Session ----------- // 
        
        User creator_user = new User("ownerUsername");
        userDB.add_user(creator_user);

        Session newSession = new Session(creator_user.getUser_id()); 
        sessionsDB.add_session(newSession);

        UserInLobby userInLobby = new UserInLobby(creator_user, newSession.getToken());
        userLobbyDB.addUserInLobby(userInLobby);
        
        String token = newSession.getToken();
        
        // ----------- Init des joiners ----------- // 
        
        User joiner1 = new User("joiner1");
        User joiner2 = new User("joiner2");
        User joiner3 = new User("joiner3");
        User joiner4 = new User("joiner4");

        // ----------- Ajout des Joiners à la Session ----------- // 
        
        UserInLobby userInLobbyJoiner1 = new UserInLobby(joiner1, token);
        UserInLobby userInLobbyJoiner2 = new UserInLobby(joiner2, token);
        UserInLobby userInLobbyJoiner3 = new UserInLobby(joiner3, token);
        UserInLobby userInLobbyJoiner4 = new UserInLobby(joiner4, token);
        
        // ----------- Setting them to Ready ----------- // 
        
        userInLobbyJoiner1.setReadyOrNot(1);
        userInLobbyJoiner2.setReadyOrNot(1);
        userInLobbyJoiner3.setReadyOrNot(1);
        userInLobbyJoiner4.setReadyOrNot(1);
        
        userLobbyDB.addUserInLobby(userInLobbyJoiner1);
        userLobbyDB.addUserInLobby(userInLobbyJoiner2);
        userLobbyDB.addUserInLobby(userInLobbyJoiner3);
        userLobbyDB.addUserInLobby(userInLobbyJoiner4);

        
        // ----------- Test que toutes les conditions sont réunis pour pouvoir lancer la game ----------- //
        given().pathParam("token", token)
            .when().get("/{token}/start")
            .then()
                .statusCode(200);
        
    }
```

The first part of this testing function create a owner user and the lobby (so we the get the token of this session) and the i create some joiner users, that i just add to the session and set them to ready.

I know the first response or HTTP code should be not found but I change it to see where my issue was.
Because when i try to build, I get a test failure on this one and it says :"1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>."

But I don't get where this error come from. I dont return any not found response anywhere (ofc the two function in the if only returns a boolean and no response in their body).

One possible idea could be that it didn't find which function to execute (i mean that there is an issue with the path and so my function isn't called).
But it would be pretty weird as when i test with insomnia request, it works well.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot for the time you took to read this ^^

Comment: You can add some logs to have a more precise idea. `then().log().all()` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issues, there was a problem in the path, that's why i get the 404.
Thanks ^^